# OutOfMemoryError in C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager

Tags: java, jsf-2, c3p0

my application is running on:

- apache-tomcat-7.0.27;
- primefaces 3.1.1;
- mysql-connector-java-5.0.8;
- jsf 2.0;
- c3p0-0.9.2-pre2;
- hibernate3;

and after a few minutes before starting server and visiting a few pages I got this:

```
Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager-Helper Thread-#0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

It's strange because I do not "stress" my system and I do only simple accesses.

I imagine this is a c3p0 issue or I'm missing something.

Anyway, this is my c3p0 configuration (*):

- HibernateConnectionProviderClass = "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider";
- HibernateC3p0MinSize = "3"
- HibernateC3p0MaxSize = "5"
- HibernateC3p0Timeout = "1800"
- HibernateC3p0IdleTestPeriod = "100"

(*) Ignore the configuration format because it's in a class and runs in execution time.

Comment: I'm not sure that `C3P0` is the culprit. Memory leaks can happen in a lot of places. You should try to trace the problem back to it's root.
This link explains a few things about `PermGen`problems and how to analyze them. The example is even for `Tomcat`.
http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/

Comment: its a good ol' c3p0/cglib leak: duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418318/hibernate-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space

Answer (score -1):

I would try adding `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` to the JAVA_OPTS variable in setenv.sh or setenv.bat on windows.  This file is in the bin folder inside your tomcat's installation directory.

Comment: The problem is that I got limited memory on the server I rent.